# Control size and scope of Struct object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, struct

I am building the design of a library and, as im not familiar with C#, was wanting to create a structure (value type) and have it be internally managed.  Meaning when someone assigns a value to said structure, it would (for this instance) verify the length of the value and do some sanitation of the value (ie turn `whitespace` into `underscores`,etc. ).

Its the controlling of the value that im amiss at.  If it was a normal class, i would just attach an event to the assignment and perform all the validations, but as a class would be overkill for the purposes of the object i am going to create, i figured a `struct` object would be the best fit.

#### Struct Design, probably not clean but what i have so far:

```
public struct ST_Keytip
{
    private string _value;

    [DefaultProperty]
    public string FooBar
    {
        get { return this._value; }
        set
        {
            if (len(value) < 1 or len(value) > 3)
            {
                throw new exception("blah blah blah....PUKE!!!!")
            }
            else
            {
                this._value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im sure its not a clean C# design but its what i would have done if it was a class object.  Basically i dont need it to be instantiated (hence why i didnt use class) and it should hold a value.  I just want to know if i can attach a value validation to a structure, and if i can How?  If not, what would be the best approach to have a value type that had limitations on the value it is assigned?

Comment: You really shouldn't call a property `value`.  It will cause ambiguity with the `value` keyword in the setter (not for the compiler, but for the reader of the code).

Comment: symantics are least of my concern right now.

Comment: That's not a good mindset.  They should be of the utmost concern.

Comment: If you were running out of gas, Would you stop at any gas station for fuel or just the ones with E85?  I would think you would do whatever it took to get gas into your vehicle but maybe not.

Comment: And I'm saying the analogy isn't appropriate.  The problems that are likely to arise out of using a property named `value` are probably more significant than the problems you'd have not using any custom class at all and just using all `string` objects.  The negative consequences of poor design here are not so high that this problem pales in comparison, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm way off the mark here, but if you're defining this as a `struct` because "i dont need it to be instantiated", then you might be in trouble seeing as `structs` are instantiated anyway when used. Perhaps you are misunderstanding the _purpose_ and _uses_ of value types (`struct`) vs reference types (`class`) and asking the wrong question here. Have you read up and understand the differences between the two? (here are some resources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664471%28VS.71%29.aspx , and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx )

Comment: In my mind i always refer to classes instantiable objects and structs as value objects.  Its immutable to dissociate structs from instantiation but its the way i keep the seperated.  As classes generally are force instantiated (ie developer must declare `new` or pass a reference to an object that has been instantiated.  Structs on the other hand do not require the `new` instantiation for object initialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutable structs are evil.  You should avoid them like the plague.

As a rule it's best to only use a struct over a class if there is a compelling reason/need to do so, and when you're fully aware of all of the consequences of using a struct.

For your case, despite the fact that your object is small, it should be a class.

Comment: The problem is that i personally feel a class with a default property is a waste of coding space.  I need to have an object that i can put length restrictions on the value it holds.  Sorta like defining a variable as `char[3]` instead of `char` or `string`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: As well, this value type would be consumed multiple times.  I can do classes, but as stated, it would literally have 1 private variable and the property would be the default.  I would prefer it not to be instantiated but also not `static`.

Comment: @GoldBishop And I'm telling you that you'll cause more problem then you'll solve using the code you have instead of a class.  If you don't think it's worth the effort to make a custom type then don't may *any* custom type and just have `string` objects that are or aren't sanitized.  If you think the readability is worth the tiny overhead of a custom type, create your class.

Comment: It was concept design...not actual implementation

Comment: On your second pt, that is what im leaning towards the more research i do.  It would be one thing if i had the infamous `Person` object with multiple properties but i have this one constricted type that is used in multiple places.  Thought it would be easier to just define a struct, or type, and do the restrictions in said object.  But seems i go back to class development ;(